# Spring JPA doesn't create my entities on mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

Hello Everybody I'm trying to create another project in Springboot but nothing happen the terminal doesn't notice any problem and just achieve to link with the cineville database but nothing happen after for creating the tables ! I don't think the packages are problematic neither...

The CinevilleApplication

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CinevilleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CinevilleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Two entities Cinema and Ville

```
@Entity
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class Cinema implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private double longitude,latitude,altitude;
    
    private int nombreSalles;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="cinema")
    private Collection<Salle> salles;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Ville ville;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class Ville {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private double longitude,latitude,altitude;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ville")
    private Collection<Cinema> cinemas;
}
```

The Application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cineville?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.port=9090
```

The pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>cineville</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>cineville</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The terminal

```
2021-04-07 22:50:27.152  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.CinevilleApplication    : Starting CinevilleApplication using Java 14.0.2 on DESKTOP-6P1QS86 with PID 6452 (C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.8.0.RELEASE\cineville\target\classes started by Utilisateur in C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.8.0.RELEASE\cineville)
2021-04-07 22:50:27.155  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.CinevilleApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-04-07 22:50:27.200  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-04-07 22:50:27.201  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-04-07 22:50:27.796  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-04-07 22:50:27.808  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 6 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-04-07 22:50:28.413  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9090 (http)
2021-04-07 22:50:28.423  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-04-07 22:50:28.423  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.44]
2021-04-07 22:50:28.511  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-04-07 22:50:28.511  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1309 ms
2021-04-07 22:50:28.789  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-04-07 22:50:28.832  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
2021-04-07 22:50:28.947  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-04-07 22:50:29.035  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-04-07 22:50:29.209  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-04-07 22:50:29.219  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2021-04-07 22:50:29.395  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-04-07 22:50:29.405  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-07 22:50:29.461  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-04-07 22:50:29.538  WARN 6452 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-04-07 22:50:29.943  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-04-07 22:50:30.478  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http) with context path ''
2021-04-07 22:50:30.487  INFO 6452 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.CinevilleApplication    : Started CinevilleApplication in 3.705 seconds (JVM running for 4.49)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found the answer and the problems was clearly the organization of the package

I had:

- com.example.demo
- com.example.dao

And the solution was only to scribe => com.example.demo.dao